# Equation number not on the right side

Tags: equations, numbering

I'm writting a numbered equation on a `\begin{equation}` environment and this is the result.

[image]

How can I put the number on the right?

Comment: We assume the `(3.1)` on the right of your equation is the number? I'm guessing you inserted that manually? Can you provide a minimal document we can use to replicate what you've shown? This minimal example should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    IS=\dfrac{\ch{[Na_2OH]}}{\ch{NaOH}+\ch{Na_2S}}\cdot 100\%
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You have:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using only basic commands....without external packages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{IS}=\frac{[\mathrm{Na}_2\mathrm{OH}]}{\mathrm{NaOH}+\mathrm{Na}_2\mathrm{S}}\cdot 100\%
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]